# Why should one exec "sh -c a.out" instead of a.out itself?

Tags: c, process, popen, execl

I'm studying Apple's implementation of `popen()` at https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/popen.c.auto.html and noticed that they do `execl(_PATH_BSHELL, "sh", "-c", command, NULL)` instead of `execl(_PATH_BSHELL, command, NULL)`.

Why would you want to (or should you) exec an executable, e.g. `a.out` via `sh -c` instead of just the executable itself?

If you exec `sh -c a.out` instead of just `a.out` itself, does the actual `a.out` process end up being a "grandchild" process and not a *child* process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would you want to (or should you) exec an executable, e.g. `a.out` via `sh -c` instead of just the executable itself?

`popen()` is designed to run shell commands that include shell syntax like `>` redirection, `|` pipes, and `&&` command chaining. It needs to pass the string through `sh -c` in order to support those constructs. If it didn't those syntactical features would be passed verbatim to the program in question as arguments.

For example, `popen("make clean && make")` should trigger two `make` invocations. Without `sh -c` it would call `make` once with three arguments, as if one had typed

```
$ make clean '&&' make
```

at the terminal.

> If you exec `sh -c a.out` instead of just `a.out` itself, does the actual `a.out` process end up being a "grandchild" process and not a *child* process?

Yes, that is correct. There will be a `sh` process in between the current process and `a.out`.

Comment: That last depends on what `sh` is. If it's bash or zsh, for example, it will exec without forking (if the command is simple enough), so it will end up being a child. Dash doesn't do that, so if you're using a system where sh is dash, it will work as you indicate.

Answer (score 0):

> that they do `execl(_PATH_BSHELL, "sh", "-c", command, NULL)` instead of `execl(_PATH_BSHELL, command, NULL)`

The latter would NOT have executed `command` directly, but `_PATH_BSHELL` (`/bin/sh`) with its `$0` set to `command` and *no arguments*, resulting in an shell expecting commands from its stdin.

Also, that syntax relies on `NULL` being defined to an explicit pointer (e.g. `((void*)0)`), and not just `0`, which is not guaranteed anywhere. While they can do that in their implementation (because they control all the headers), it's not what you should do in application code.

And no, `execl(command, command, (void*)NULL)` wouldn't have executed `command` directly either, unless `command` is **a)** a full path and **b)** in an executable format (binary or a script starting with a she-bang `#!` -- the latter being a *non-standard* extension). If `command` was a simple command name to be looked up in `PATH` (like `pwd` or `a.out`) or an executable script not starting with a she-bang, you should've used `execlp` instead of `execl`.

The `exec[lv]p[e]` functions do some of the things a shell does (like looking through the `PATH`), but not all of them (like running multiple commands or expanding variables): that's why functions like `system(3)` or `popen(3)` pass the command to `/bin/sh -c`. Notice that with both it's `/bin/sh`, not the user's login shell or the `$SHELL` from the environment which is used.

> If you exec `sh -c a.out` instead of just `a.out` itself, does the actual `a.out` process end up being a "grandchild" process and not a child process?

Only with some shells like `dash`. Not with `bash`, `ksh93`, `mksh`, `zsh`, `yash`, `busybox`, etc, which will execute `a.out` directly instead of forking and waiting for it.