# Is there a way to determine the "grandchild" pid_t of a process spawned with "sh -c"?

Tags: c, linux, process, popen, child-process

This question follows from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164339/why-does-read-block-on-a-pipe-until-the-write-end-is-closed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163331/why-should-one-exec-sh-c-a-out-instead-of-a-out-itself).

To bolster my understanding of spawning processes and redirecting pipes, I've written `popen`-like function `popen2()` -- below -- that returns the `pid_t` of the spawned child process.

*Note: the implementation of `popen2()` spawns the child process by `exec`ing `sh -c cmd` instead of just `cmd` because of the explanations in favor of this approach at the second linked question.*

The code at bottom is not terribly long, but to cut to the chase: `a.out` spawns `child.out` as well as `ps aux | grep child` to get visual confirmation of child processes' stats before printing out what it thinks is `child.out`'s pid.

A commenter at [the second linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163331/why-should-one-exec-sh-c-a-out-instead-of-a-out-itself) pointed out that processes spawned via `sh -c` may end up being either *child* or *grandchild* processes, depending on what `sh` is.
I unintentionally verified this by observing that on my host -- where `sh` resolves to `/bin/bash` -- running `a.out` shows that `child.out` is run as a child process:

```
$ g++ --version && gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror ./main.c && ./a.out
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

p2 stdout:
user     3004534  0.0  0.0   4028   732 pts/14   S+   17:51   0:00 ./child.out
user     3004535  0.0  0.0  11176  2932 pts/14   S+   17:51   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep child
user     3004537  0.0  0.0  12780   968 pts/14   S+   17:51   0:00 grep child

p.pid[3004534]
```

...whereas in a docker container on the same host -- where `sh` resolves to `/bin/dash` -- running `a.out` shows that `child.out` is run as a grandchild process:

```
Step 63/63 : RUN ./a.out
 ---> Running in 7a355740577b
p2 stdout:
root           7  0.0  0.0   2384   760 ?        S    00:55   0:00 sh -c ./child.out
root           8  0.0  0.0   2384   760 ?        S    00:55   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep child
root           9  0.0  0.0   2132   680 ?        S    00:55   0:00 ./child.out
root          11  0.0  0.0   3080   880 ?        S    00:55   0:00 grep child

p.pid[7]
```

**My question is: in `a.out`'s code, is there a way to get the `pid_t` of the executed command in a way that abstracts whether the actual command is a *child* process' or a *grandchild* process?**

To give some context: I want to be able to kill `child.out`. By observation, in the environment where my `popen2()` spawns child and grandchild processes, sending the *child* process a `SIGTERM` kills only the *child* process, i.e. `sh -c child.out` but not the *grandchild* process, i.e. `child.out`, which is what I really want to kill.

---

The code:

```
// main.c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define INVALID_FD (-1)
#define INVALID_PID (-1)

typedef enum PipeEnd {
  READ_END  = 0,
  WRITE_END = 1
} PipeEnd;

typedef int Pipe[2];

/** Encapsulates information about a created child process. */
typedef struct popen2_t {
  bool  success;  ///< true if the child process was spawned.
  Pipe  stdin;    ///< parent -> stdin[WRITE_END] -> child's stdin
  Pipe  stdout;   ///< child -> stdout[WRITE_END] -> parent reads stdout[READ_END]
  Pipe  stderr;   ///< child -> stderr[WRITE_END] -> parent reads stderr[READ_END]
  pid_t pid;      ///< child process' pid
} popen2_t;

/** dup2( p[pe] ) then close and invalidate both ends of p */
static void dupFd( Pipe p, const PipeEnd pe, const int fd ) {
  dup2( p[pe], fd);
  close( p[READ_END] );
  close( p[WRITE_END] );
  p[READ_END] = INVALID_FD;
  p[WRITE_END] = INVALID_FD;
}

/**
 * Redirect a parent-accessible pipe to the child's stdin, and redirect the
 * child's stdout and stderr to parent-accesible pipes.
 */
popen2_t popen2( const char* cmd ) {
  popen2_t r = { false,
    { INVALID_FD, INVALID_FD },
    { INVALID_FD, INVALID_FD },
    { INVALID_FD, INVALID_FD },
    INVALID_PID };

  if ( -1 == pipe( r.stdin ) ) { goto end; }
  if ( -1 == pipe( r.stdout ) ) { goto end; }
  if ( -1 == pipe( r.stderr ) ) { goto end; }

  switch ( (r.pid = fork()) ) {
    case -1: // Error
      goto end;

    case 0: // Child process
      dupFd( r.stdin, READ_END, STDIN_FILENO );
      dupFd( r.stdout, WRITE_END, STDOUT_FILENO );
      dupFd( r.stderr, WRITE_END, STDERR_FILENO );

      {
        char* argv[] = { (char*)"sh", (char*)"-c", (char*)cmd, NULL };

        if ( -1 == execvp( argv[0], argv ) ) { exit(0); }
      }
  }

  // Parent process
  close( r.stdin[READ_END] );
  r.stdin[READ_END] = INVALID_FD;
  close( r.stdout[WRITE_END] );
  r.stdout[WRITE_END] = INVALID_FD;
  close( r.stderr[WRITE_END] );
  r.stderr[WRITE_END] = INVALID_FD;
  r.success = true;

end:
  if ( ! r.success ) {
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdin[READ_END] ) { close( r.stdin[READ_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdin[WRITE_END] ) { close( r.stdin[WRITE_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdout[READ_END] ) { close( r.stdout[READ_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdout[WRITE_END] ) { close( r.stdout[WRITE_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stderr[READ_END] ) { close( r.stderr[READ_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stderr[WRITE_END] ) { close( r.stderr[WRITE_END] ); }

    r.stdin[READ_END] = r.stdin[WRITE_END] =
      r.stdout[READ_END] = r.stdout[WRITE_END] =
      r.stderr[READ_END] = r.stderr[WRITE_END] = INVALID_FD;
  }

  return r;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  (void)argc;
  (void)argv;
  popen2_t p = popen2( "./child.out" );
  int status = 0;

  {
    char buf[4096] = { '\0' };
    popen2_t p2 = popen2( "ps aux | grep child" );
    waitpid( p2.pid, &status, 0 );

    read( p2.stdout[READ_END], buf, sizeof buf );
    printf( "p2 stdout:\n%s\n", buf );
  }

  printf( "p.pid[%d]\n", p.pid );

  {
    pid_t wpid = waitpid( p.pid, &status, 0 );

    return wpid == p.pid && WIFEXITED( status ) ? WEXITSTATUS( status ) : -1;
  }
}
```

```
// child.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  char buf[128] = { '\0' };

  snprintf( buf, sizeof buf, "%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
  write( STDOUT_FILENO, buf, strlen( buf ) );
  sleep( 1 );

  snprintf( buf, sizeof buf, "%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
  write( STDOUT_FILENO, buf, strlen( buf ) );
  sleep( 1 );

  snprintf( buf, sizeof buf, "%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
  write( STDOUT_FILENO, buf, strlen( buf ) );
  sleep( 1 );

  snprintf( buf, sizeof buf, "%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ );
  write( STDOUT_FILENO, buf, strlen( buf ) );
  sleep( 1 );
  return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: The command run by the shell also can be your grand-grandchild. If you want to be able kill whatever stuff runs in the shell, you should use a *process group*. But that's pointless anyway: there's a very good reason why there's no `popen2()`: because there's no obvious way to fix the buffering issue, and except for a selected set of commands, it will result in a deadlock. And your code has a lot of other problems (as using exit() instead of _exit() in a forked child, assuming that waitpid won't be interrupted, etc).

Comment: @user414777 - dude! You led me to exactly what I needed: setting the pgid of the child process, then sending a signal to the _process group_. I learned a bunch from the research your comment inspired me to look into. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little above my paygrade, but since there haven't been any other answers, I'll post what I ended up doing, which is based on user414777's comment, and appears to work.

My approach was not to get the `pid_t` of the grandchild process, but to set the child process to be a process group leader. By doing so, if I send a signal to the process group (`killpg()`), that has the effect of the signal reaching the grandchild process. This is reflected in the addition of `setpgid()` below.

```
popen2_t popen2( const char* cmd ) {
  popen2_t r = { false,
    { INVALID_FD, INVALID_FD },
    { INVALID_FD, INVALID_FD },
    { INVALID_FD, INVALID_FD },
    INVALID_PID };

  if ( -1 == pipe( r.stdin ) ) { goto end; }
  if ( -1 == pipe( r.stdout ) ) { goto end; }
  if ( -1 == pipe( r.stderr ) ) { goto end; }

  switch ( (r.pid = fork()) ) {
    case -1: // Error
      goto end;

    case 0: // Child process
      dupFd( r.stdin, READ_END, STDIN_FILENO );
      dupFd( r.stdout, WRITE_END, STDOUT_FILENO );
      dupFd( r.stderr, WRITE_END, STDERR_FILENO );
      setpgid( getpid(), getpid() ); // This is the relevant change

      {
        char* argv[] = { (char*)"sh", (char*)"-c", (char*)cmd, NULL };

        if ( -1 == execvp( argv[0], argv ) ) { exit(0); }
      }
  }

  // Parent process
  close( r.stdin[READ_END] );
  r.stdin[READ_END] = INVALID_FD;
  close( r.stdout[WRITE_END] );
  r.stdout[WRITE_END] = INVALID_FD;
  close( r.stderr[WRITE_END] );
  r.stderr[WRITE_END] = INVALID_FD;
  r.success = true;

end:
  if ( ! r.success ) {
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdin[READ_END] ) { close( r.stdin[READ_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdin[WRITE_END] ) { close( r.stdin[WRITE_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdout[READ_END] ) { close( r.stdout[READ_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stdout[WRITE_END] ) { close( r.stdout[WRITE_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stderr[READ_END] ) { close( r.stderr[READ_END] ); }
    if ( INVALID_FD != r.stderr[WRITE_END] ) { close( r.stderr[WRITE_END] ); }

    r.stdin[READ_END] = r.stdin[WRITE_END] =
      r.stdout[READ_END] = r.stdout[WRITE_END] =
      r.stderr[READ_END] = r.stderr[WRITE_END] = INVALID_FD;
  }

  return r;
}
```